# Pytest/Python - Assert text in a position of a line in a file

Tags: file, text, position, pytest, assert

I'm new to the wonderful world of Python/Pytest/Pywinauto, etc and I'm by no means a dev, so please go easy on me :)

I'm trying to run a test to assert the text from a file as per below:

```
    import pytest
    
    
    def test_fileContains123456():
        line = open("my_file.html", "r").readlines()[20]
        assert r"THIS1              123456 YES" in line
```

This correctly asserts that the text is present in the file on that particular line. Is there a way of improving the accuracy of this so that it picks it up from the position on that particular line? In this case the position of the text to be asserted is according to Notepad++ Column 101 on the line or position 1,683 in the file.

Also, is there any way the above code could be improved on?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to test an HTML file whose content can change yet its syntactic structure may remain the same. In other words content of particular lines within the file can change but the parsed or rendered result would remain identical. This means that you want to improve 2 things:

1. **accuracy** - assert that the given string is inside particular HTML element.
2. **leeway** - when the content of the file changes yet the crucial HTML element still has the correct string, you don't want your test to break.

To achieve this, you need to parse the HTML file. Python's built-in [parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) is not optimal for what you want but you can try some third party package instead, e.g. **[lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/)**.

**my_file.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span id="needle">THIS1 123456 YES</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.py**:

```py
import pytest
from lxml import html

def test_fileContains123456():
    parsed = html.parse('my_file.html').getroot()
    assert parsed.get_element_by_id('needle').text_content() == 'THIS1 123456 YES'
```

How exactly you construct your test assertion depends on the exact content of the HTML file. My example assumes that the HTML element has `id` set to `needle` and its content is supposed to match exactly the search string. There are however other ways of matching elements, e.g. using CSS syntax (see [`cssselect()`](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods)).